# Fetch data from action payload in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Below are my reducer and action creator.

```
hotelAdded: (hotels, action) => {
      hotels.list.push(action.payload);
    },
```

```
export const addHotel = (hotel, history) =>
  hotelApiCallBegan({
    url: `${hotelUrl}new/`,
    method: "post",
    data: hotel,
    onSuccess: hotelAdded.type,
    redirect: history,
  });
```

Now I would like to retrieve `slug` object from `action.payload` but I am struggling with how to achieve that. To add some context. I am creating a hotel object. After creating the object i can see the payload as as shown in `redux-logger`

```
payload:
active: true
address: "N/A"
air_conditioner: false
airport_transport: false
bar_lounge: false
cards_accepted: false
checkin: null
slug:"Paul  hotel"
checkout: null
```

How do I retrieve the `slug` object so that i can use in redirecting to the newly formed object page?

Answer (score 0):

Mmm I don't recognize either the reducer function and the action creator.

An action creation return an object with two properties `type` (mandatory) and `payload`

```js
function actionCreator(hotel) {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_HOTEL',
    payload: hotel
  }
}
```

In the other hand a reducer function usually use a switch statement and return a new state object (not the modified state). Like:

```js
function hotelReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_HOTEL':
      return { ...state, [...state.hotels, action.payload ] };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

The question is, are you sure you are using Redux properly?

Comment: I am creating reducers with ```@reduxjs/toolkit```